# How can I use this API?

Tags: json, api

how would I be able to return every asteroid from this API rather than specific asteroids  [http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query={query}&limit={limit}](http://asterank.com/api/asterank?query=%7Bquery%7D&limit=%7Blimit%7D)

Comment: If the query is required then I imagine you'd have to devise a set of queries which would cover all possible results, and pass those queries with absurdly large limit values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the point of an API. You should then bulk download their database and parse it to your needs.